# Missing blocks on live system

Tags: blocks, ce-1.9.0.1, ajax

We switch our shop live (changed domain, cleared cache) and now ajax requests returns empty blocks.

Problem accrued with the Hardik/Ajaxcart extension. If you add an article to your cart it makes a ajax request and updates some blocks in the view.

Ajax requests is ok and does return data but blocks are missing:

```
/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3...0bWw,/product/399/form_key/kKNZaJaumNoauq1z/
```

Here the blocks are supposed to load in `Hardik_Ajaxcart_Model_Response::addUpdatedBlocks()`

```
    $updated_blocks = unserialize(Mage::getStoreConfig('ajaxcart/general/update_blocks'));

    if ($updated_blocks) {
        $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
        $res = array();

        foreach ($updated_blocks['id'] as $index => $block) {
            $value = $layout->getBlock($updated_blocks['xml'][$index]);
```

Settings are loaded into `$updated_blocks` but `$layout->getBlock()` returns nothing.

**Update**

Could this be apache config or proxy?

```
Via:1.1 rproxy (squid)
X-Cache:MISS from rproxy
```

**Update 2**

Looks like proxy is eating POST parameters...

Comment: Do you have any clue from hardik ? did you try recompile ?

Comment: try contacting hardik for the error

Comment: recompile? what do you mean? The hardik extension works locally just fine (same files, db and url) but not on live server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an additional / in Apache URL rewrites that caused the POST parameters to get lost. Without the POST parameters ajax query did not load the those blocks.

Comment: Why do the POST parameters matter? the cart gets updated perfectly in a normal page reload. It's just the `getBlock` doesn't return anything. So that means the POST parameters reached their destination. How do they relate to each other?

Comment: @MilindR This shop was using the Hardik_Ajaxcart extension to reload the cart dynamically.

Comment: I am also using the same extension. the getBlock() function is failing (returning `bool(false)`)for any blockname. Can you tell me which line in .htaccess is the URL rewrite you're talking about?

Comment: the worst part is that the AJAX response doesn't even have the JSON object with the updated block names.